# How do I change highchart axis arrow direction style?

Tags: highcharts

I use highchart library.
If I change x-axis or y-axis direction style, for example arrow style, is this possible?

Originally, I know that axis style is fixed.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you want it to look like ?